# Quick question regarding the work of a dynamical system

Tags: physics, education

I'm sitting in on a course in dynamics and I've noticed something very strange that I can't get my mind around.  So when they do problems that involve springs, they are saying that the work is 
$$U_s=-\frac{1}{2}k(s_f-s_0)^2$$

However, I know that Hooke's Law says that the force of a spring is given by $F=-ks$, and so to find work we just integrate with respect to $s$:

$$U_s^*=-k\int_{s_0}^{s_f} s\: ds =-\frac{k}{2}(s_f^2-s_0^2) $$

Clearly $U_s\neq U_s^*$, but they continually use $U_s$ as the formula for work.  Could anyone clarify why?  Bellow is a link to an example of a problem that does this.

http://faculty.washington.edu/reinhall/ME230/Soultions_nonassigned/Chap18_19.pdf#page=3

Comment: Since $ \  s \ $ in Hooke's Law represents the "displacement from equilibrium" of the spring, the limits in the second integral should be $ \ s \ = \ 0 \ $ to $ \ s \ = \ s_f \ - \ s_0 \ $ .  (I will readily concede that many discussions of "spring potential energy" are handled sloppily, in that the distinction between _position_ and _displacement_ is not made clear.)  The $ \ s_0 \ $ here is being used as "initial position" , which means that the second integral should probably be written as $$ \ -k \ \int_{s_0}^{s_f} \ \ (s \ - \ s_0) \ \ ds \ \ . $$